# Wordpress login logout on menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm pretty new to WordPress and I'm trying to import a website of mine (which it's all in PHP) to WordPress. The thing is, my NavBar has this code:

```
<ul>
<li>bla bla bla</li>
<li>bla bla bla</li>
<li><?php include_once('Login_Status.php') ?></li>
</ul>
```

That login script (which is a fictious name of course) runs a simple code that checks if the user is logged in and if he is logged it returns:

```
<li>Member Area</li>
<li>Logout</li>
```

else, it returns:

```
<li>Login</li>
```

So, now that I'm trying to import the website to WordPress and I'm on the nav bar part of the process, I'm not seeing how I'm going to include this PHP file on the `wp_nav_menu($args)` function.

Any idea or link where I can read further on this?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would set this up would be to just add the login, logout and members area links to your nav in the menu manager. Then you can use the [Nav Menu Roles](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-roles/) plugin to conditionally display those menu items.

Another way to do this would be to setup two nav menus and conditionally display them using the `is_user_logged_in` function.

```
$location = is_user_logged_in() ? 'logged_in_menu' : 'logged_out_menu';
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => $location,
    /* ... */
));
```

This is assuming you have the menus *logged_in_menu* and *logged_out_menu* registered using the `register_nav_menu` function. I would use this solution if the logged in and logged out menus are significantly different. I don't think that's the case for you.